# MySQL Where IN Clause returns different result

Tags: mysql, where-clause, in-clause

I am new in MySQL, I would like to understand how IN clause works.

In MySQL when I try to use in IN clause as such:

```
Select *
From `table`
WHERE `code` IN (1,2)
```

It works and it returns the record

```
Select *
From `table`
WHERE `code` IN (3)
```

It does not work.

Column value in DB:

```
-----------------
|    `code`     |
|    1,3,2      |
-----------------
```

desc:
`code` VARCHAR(100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When string is compared with a number, the string is converted to a number. So this:

```sql
SELECT '1,3,2' IN (1, 2) -- true
```

Would force MySQL to convert `1,3,2` to `1`; it parses 1 and ignores everything after comma. You can confirm this behavior by re-arranging the values and it will no longer match:

```sql
SELECT '3,1,2' IN (1, 2) -- false
```

A hackish solution is to do something like this:

```sql
WHERE CONCAT(',', code, ',') LIKE '%,1,%'
   OR CONCAT(',', code, ',') LIKE '%,2,%'
```

But the correct solution is to store comma separated values as separate rows.